# jQuery POST using Django CSRF - Remove X-CSRFToken Header After?

Tags: jquery, django, csrf, django-csrf

I'm following the [instructions here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#csrf-ajax).  And the Django folks say to run this before my Ajax post request to include the CSRF token.

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

This works but do I need to remove that token from the headers **after** my POST?  I don't want all jQuery post requests including it because I figure it could leak the token.

So how do I undo the ajax setup after running the POST?

And do I need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to, as it checks that it's not a cross-domain request before adding the header.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.  I guess it gets set before each request, and it doesn't stick around for the next request.